# MySQL - Adding VAT, where required

Tags: php, mysql

I have a range of products that do or do not include VAT. I always want to show the price including VAT to the customer so I have a flag that states whether the price includes VAT or not.  Currently I add VAT in PHP which means the sorting is something off as MySQL sorts on the base price and sometimes VAT can make the results out of order.

What I would like then is to automatically add VAT to prices, where it is needed, within the MySQL query.  How can I achieve this?

My products table look like this:

```
product_id, product_dayprice, product_weekprice, product_includevat
```

product_includevat is simply a bool i.e. 1 or 0... VAT is stored as a PHP variable

My sort code looks like this which is designed to put products with a price of 0 at the end

```
CASE product_daypriceWHEN 0 then 40000 ELSE product_dayprice END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if that `product_include_vat` is a bool field, then it'd be as simple as

```
SELECT product_weekprice + (product_weekprice * vat_rate * product_includevat)
```

if the includevat field is false, it'll evaluate to an integer 0, and your vat gets zeroed out in the multiplication.

Comment: Perfect... Can I assign that back to the original field name so I can access it via `product_weekprice` or would I have to create a new one?

Comment: you could, but given that vat rates can change when the political winds change, you might want to store the standard base rate and store the base+vat value somewhere else, in case the politicians blow more hot air than usual.

Answer (score 0):

You should not calculate VAT dynamically on every step. Calculate it once, and save all data you have, e.g. either netto and VAT as separate values, or brutto and netto, or brutto and VAT.

Why the redundancy? One: Rounding errors when adding prices. Two: Some data has to be permanent after stuff is sold, even if the VAT rate changes. This is not valid for your database of current prices, but for your customer history you have to know how much VAT was included at the time of the sale. If you recalculate it every time, and the VAT rate increases, you'll pay too much to your tax office.

Comment: well in that case, the sold history is another table, where values are copied  into anyway, so ... vat remains from time of sale. There is no problem doing dynamically, i actually believe its a redundancy to store the price with vat. Harder to mantain.